# How do I properly submit an object into an array using Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJs and writing some throw away code. I'm trying to create an object Bookmark and push it into an array.

HTML:

```
<h2>Create a new bookmark </h2>
                <form class="form-group" ng-submit="createBookmark(newBookmark)" novalidate>
                    <!--Title-->
                    <h4>Bookmark Title</h4>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="newBookmark.title">
                    <!--Url-->          
                    <h4>Bookmark Url</h4>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="newBookmark.url">
                    <!--Submit-->
                    <button type="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="crForm" ng-click="stopCreating()">Save</button>
                </form>
```

JS:

```
function resetCreateForm(){
        $scope.newBookmark = {
            title : '',
            url : '',
            category : $scope.currentCategory.name
        };   
    }

    function createBookmark(bookmark) {
        bookmark.id = $scope.bookmarks.length;
        bookmark.category = $scope.currentCategory.name;
        $scope.bookmarks.push(bookmark);

        resetCreateForm();
    }
    $scope.createBookmark = createBookmark;
    $scope.resetCreateForm = resetCreateForm;
```

Object:

```
$scope.bookmarks = [
        {id: 0, title: "Title1", url: "www.Title1.com", category: "Development"},
        {id: 1, title: "Title2", url: "www.Title2.com", category: "Development"}
```

];

Module and Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('list',[]);

app.controller('listController', function($scope){
```

For some reason it does not work, so far I think it's from changes in the Angular version but I could not find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind `resetCreateForm` & `createBookmark` in `$scope` of controller so that you can access them from view.

```
//place this inside your controller
$scope.resetCreateForm = resetCreateForm;
$scope.createBookmark= createBookmark;
```

Also you don't need to call function on `ng-click`, on click of button `ng-submit` will get called. Remove `ng-click="stopCreating()"`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I forgot to add the code to that in the post. I've done that and it still does not work.

Comment: So I removed the ng-click and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MarinTudor that's what I ask to do in my answer :) Glad to help you, Thanks :)